# How do i switch to development job after having experience in Software Testing?

Tags: software-development

I am Software Testing Engineer with 2.5 yrs of experience (both manual and automation testing.). I feel like i am stuck in this job and aimless that how to switch to development.Also i cannot just leave the job and go due to financial situation.Each day i feel like i am going in depression.A fear has started to grave inside me that with my years of experience i cannot get development job this is also due to companies are not considering my testing resume for the development vacancies. I am having some good coding skills but in my current company there is no chance i could switch. Please suggest me are there companies which can consider my profile and what skill i should learn for them?

Comment: Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or **"what skills should I learn?"**). Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do.

Comment: edited..pardon my language.I am seeking advice from industry experts who can see the path ahead but i can't :(

Answer (score 3):

Do development on your own time.

Write a few applications and build a code library.  If you can do some work for a non-profit or charity, all the better.  That gets you real experience that you can put on your resume.

A strength that you can emphasize is that as a tester, you learned to be wary of certain coding techniques and pitfalls and how to avoid them.

Everything you do is relevant.  Remember that.  It's how you sell it that counts.

I've done desktop support, testing, maintenance coding AND development.  I've made the change you want to make.  Take a look at a developer's resume and see how what you are doing translates, and transfer your skills over.

Add that to the volunteer work, and you should be set.

Answer (score 3):

Contribute to open source projects. Many of them are in desperate need of good coders. If you are as good as you think you are, in no time (say in a year or two) you will make a name for yourself with your committed code. Just don't go into game programming if you you want to be taken seriously by corporate america. Do something that is going to be useful to businesses to increase your chanhces of getting noticed as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen around me, you will *not* move up the ladder in the same company.

You'll have to prove your skills in another field to *another* company.

If you can work and make demos of what you can achieve as personal projects, you can start at the bottom of the ladder as a developer at companies who seek new employees.

The fact that you have experience as a tester will look nice on your CV, but it will be used only to increase your chances of having a job as a dev, it will not help the salary.

Aside from a developer's job, you might consider management as well. There are challenges there, and it's not un-common for former testers to get management roles.